# JS Regular Expression to match function params from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string-parsing

I have a string like this: `matrix(10, 0, 1, 0, -198, 23)`

Then I need to match the arguments from that function and put in array:

```
var regexp = /.../gi
var match = regexp.exe('matrix(10, 0, 1, 0, -198, 23)');

console.debug(match) // must return: [10, 0, 1, 0, -198, 23]
```

I'm not very familiar with regular expression, but I think will be the fastest way to do the job.

split string is not possible in this case.

Performance test for the awnsers: http://jsperf.com/regexp-match-vs-string-split

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: lot's of fail regular expressions....

Comment: `/[\+\-\d\s,]+/.exec( str )` ?

Comment: Or you searching for a str or do you just want the numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'matrix(10, 0, 1, 0, -198, 23)'.match(/-?\d+/g)
```

Comment: Sorry, but it fail, `-198` has returned `198`

Answer (score 1):

Three steps:

1. Use regex to get contents of parens
2. replace the parens themselves and with nothing
3. split on comma followed by 0 or more white space

```
var str = 'matrix(10, 0, 1, 0, -198, 23)',
    regex = /\(.*\)/,
    arr;

str = str.match(regex)[0];
str = str.replace(/[()]/g, '');
arr = str.split(/,\s+/);

​console.log(arr);​
```

Comment: it's not working... the first match returns null and the split don't exist on javascript as default...

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: As I said in the question, split string isn't possible in this case. But your code work, the performance is poor, test for your self: http://jsperf.com/regexp-match-vs-string-split

Comment: In Chrome, at least, the performance of my solution is approximately equal to the accepted one. In addition, it's a general solution that doesn't just capture integer arguments. It will capture all arguments.